# Passing input hidden params through urllib2 POST request

Tags: single-sign-on, urllib2, cas

I need to make POST request to CAS SSO server login page, and CAS login page has few input hidden params which are dynamically populated through java. I don't know how to read these hidden param values from response and pass in to CAS server. Without passing these hidden params I am not able to login.

Does any one how to read input hidden param values from urllib2 response? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the answer please?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! We can use BeautifulSoup to parse html content and get the input hidden param values. And inturn we can pass these captured params in POST request.